# if...radio is checked alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I'm trying to write a piece of code which use the user choice in a form. 
The code should give an alert window with the name of the radio selected but doesn't work, it only show the A alert either A is selector or B is selected.
This is the form

```
<FORM>
<input type="radio" name="search_type" value="A"/>type A<br/>
<input type="radio" name="search_type" value="B"/>type B<br/>
</FORM>
```

and this is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="search_type"]').change(function() {
        if ($('input:radio[name="search_type"]').val() == 'A'){
                alert('type A');
        };
        if ($('input:radio[name="search_type"]').val() == 'B'){
                alert('type B');
        };
    });
});
```

Here you can find the running code: http://jsfiddle.net/ur7cc/
Can anybody please tell me why it isn't working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use with `:checked` selector for `.val()` when dealing with `radio/checkbox`. Alternatively you can use `$(this).val()` where `this` is basically the radio that triggered the change. See below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="search_type"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'A'){
                alert('type A');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == 'B'){
                alert('type B');
        }
    });
});
```

To use with `:checked` selector,

```
$('input:radio[name="search_type"]:checked').val()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ur7cc/1/

Answer (score 2):

use `$(this)` instead.
Here is a simplified version.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="search_type"]').change(function() {
        alert("Type: "+$(this).val());
    });
});
​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ur7cc/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code that I wrote and tested. It works. It writes out the status of the checkbox in a different one. Give it a shot. It worked for me.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="alert(this.name);" name="A"/> button A<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="alert(this.name);" name="B"/> button B<br>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `$('input:radio[name="search_type"]')` selector returns an array object.  You are overcomplicating this. No need to use it again. Here is much simpler method using the retrieved object:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

 $('input:radio[name="search_type"]').change(function() {
    alert ("type "+$(this).val());
  })
})
```